# Assigning a pointer to next node in the list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have built a structure called User.

Because I am using the User is several data structures, the structure only stores data about the user

```
typedef struct{
    long id;
    char *name;
    char *surname;
    int age;
    char gender;
    char *username;
    char *password;
    char *description;
    char *hobbies;
}User;
```

Now I want to create a linked list for Women so I created

```
typedef struct{
    User *userWoman;
    struct Women *next;
}Women;
```

Now when I am trying to assign a pointer to the next pointer:

```
void push(Women **head,User *woman){
    if((*head)->next == NULL){
        (*head) -> userWoman = woman;
    }
    else{
        Women *newWoman = malloc(sizeof(Women));
        if (newWoman == NULL){
            printf("Allocation of newWoman failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        newWoman -> userWoman = woman;
        (*head)->next = newWoman;
    }
}
```

I get the error: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'struct Women *' from 'Women *'

How can I declare next? it must be of the type Women

Comment: You have a type-alias `Women` (defined after the structure),  but you don't have a type `struct Women`. Think about how you define structures *without* the `typedef`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude shouldn't I use struct to create a pointer to a struct I am currently defending?

Comment: `typedef struct Women { User *userWoman; struct Women *next; }Women;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a structure and an alias in one step. This is legal, of course, yet the type alias is not known at the time the structure's members are parsed. So type alias `Women` is not known at the time the members are parsed. You probably got a compiler error when writing `Women *next`; And `struct Women *next` does not lead to a compiler error at this point, yet it is treated as a forward declaration of an incomplete type.

Give the structure a name and use this for declaring members of this type:

```
typedef struct WomenStruct {
    User *userWoman;
    struct WomenStruct *next;
} Women;
```

Later, `Women*` and `struct WomenStruct*` will be synonyms, and it is exactly the same as if you wrote...

```
struct WomenStruct {
    User *userWoman;
    struct WomenStruct *next;
};
typedef struct WomenStruct Women;  // let "Women" be an alias for "struct WomenStruct"
```

Comment: why to use 2 different names rather than `typedef struct Women { User *userWoman; struct Women *next; } Women;` ?

Comment: @bruno: using the same name is legal, of course; Its just personal opinion/habit to use different ones.

Comment: @StephanLechner So what does struct WomenStruct do? does the name of the structure using  typedef is the one in the end (Women)?